# Is this a possible part of the solution to the Collatz Conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory, collatz-conjecture

I'm not trying to prove the Collatz Conjecture, but I think I may have found a pattern that could help solve it. This looks at the number of times a number will go up and down before reaching 1. For example, 2 goes up no times and down once to reach 1. This could be notated as 2 = 0 # 1. Now, look at 5. 5 goes up once and down 4 times. This could similarly be notated as 5 = 1 # 4, which also equals 1 # (0 # 2). Clearly, 5 goes on longer than 2 in the Collatz sequence. 5 also goes on longer than 2 in this sequence. Now, think of a number, n, which equals n # n. This would also make this number equal to (n # n) # (n # n). This number would go on infinitely in a Collatz sequence and in this sequence of up and downs. n, though, wouldn't be a whole number because if a number went to infinity or stayed in a loop, it would go up and down infinite times. There are several other cases in this with two or three variables, but I was just curious if this idea even worked.

Comment: I don't see much here.  You want to keep track of the number of times you hit an odd number or an even number.  Ok.  What comes next?

Comment: The collatz sequence is far too dynamic. There is no hope at all anymore for an "easy" proof. Concerning loops : It is already known that a loop different from $1-4-2$ would be unimaginably long , but this does not rule out such a loop. And even if we could rule out those loops , there could still be divergent trajectories. So , such approaches can give nothing new , those methods have been exhausted.

Comment: I was just wondering if this was another way to look at the Collatz Conjecture.

Comment: You asked whether the pattern can help solve the conjecture. Patterns won't solve Collatz , this is virtually sure now. We will need other "big guns" for the solution. It is well possible that Collatz can't be solved (noone can be sure that this is possible). In fact, a generalized version is known to be undecidable.

Comment: The formula for the k-th odd term of the sequence is $s_k=\frac{3^k \cdot n +3^{k-1}+\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-2}{\displaystyle3^j\cdot \displaystyle2^{\sum _ {i=1} ^{k-1-j} {a_i}}}}{\displaystyle 2^{\sum _{i=1}^{k} {a_i}}}$according to your definition if n # n you have $s_k=s_n=1$ and  also $k=n =\sum _{i=1}^{k} {a_i}$ this  can not be

Comment: Isn't that what I proved, but just simpler?

Comment: “Loops are very Long” we have manually tested that there are no loops with small numbers except 1,2,4. For large numbers x gets replaced by a very good approximation of x * 3^m / 2^n. Using Euclid you show that n, m must be _very_ large for these to be the same. Like many billions.

Comment: And statistically, every step x -> (3x+1) / 2^n multiplies x be 3/4 on average, so long loops are very, very unlikely-but not impossible.

Comment: A disproof of Collatz is virtually hopeless : We know that nontrivial loops would be awfully long , so to find a nontrivial loop is virtually hopeless. Even if we hit a start value leading to a divergent trajectory , we have no way to prove that this trajectory actually is diverging. It could break down at very high levels and finally reach $1$. So, the best hope is a proof of Collatz , but this seems to be out of reach as well.

Comment: What we know clearly speaks for the truth of the Collatz conjecture.

Comment: no number reaching 1 can have an (n # n) representation. This is an increasing sequence (1 odd step followed by 1 division, followed by 1 odd step...) and the starting number must be of the form $a2^n-1$ for this to work. $n=a2^n-1$ has a limited number of integer solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's precisely one number among all the 2-adic numbers having the representation $n\textrm {hash} n$ and it's $-1$.

This follows from the fact the $(3x+1)/2$ conjecture is topologically conjugate to the tent map, which in turn means there are precisely two fixed points, and these are easily shown to be $-1$ and $0$.

Zero doesn't translate into $n\textrm {hash} n$ when going $3x+1$ but $-1$ does.

The two points of period $2$ in the $(3x+1)/2$ conjecture are period $3$ in the $3x+1$ conjecture so can't be $n\textrm {hash} n$ either.

What you're writing about is the relative frequencies of downs vs ups and this has been analysed at length. You can take it a little further with Littlewood Offord theory, which Terrence Tao does in his 2007 blog on the subject.

Some of the greatest real analysis experts in the world have worked on this and the concensus seems to be that analysis just doesn't have the tools to resolve down to fine enough resolution to prove the conjecture. One way of looking at this, is that the relative frequencies of the ups and downs don't quite hold enough information to show where a sequence goes, and that you need to somehow use the full information of the the actual sequence and order of ups and downs in order to resolve where it goes.

This is typical of some of these longstanding problems, they are often *sharp* in the sense that you cannot throw information away along the way, all the info needs to be used.

Answer (score 1):

If, for some positive integer $n$, $n$ *matches* $n\ \#\ n$, then, by definition, the Collatz trajectory of $n$ reaches $1$ in $2n$ steps (*i.e.* in a finite number of steps), and $n$ is not a counterexample to the Collatz conjecture.

Comment: So am I correct?

Comment: I think that the notation you are using is misleading ; $u\ \#\ d$ should be seen as an equivalence class, not as a number (for example $2\ \#\ 7 = \{12, 13\}$). Anyway, assuming that $n = n\ \#\ n$, you could write $n$ in the form of an incredibly complex expression involving $n$'s and $\#$'s, however this expression would still be equal to $n$.